# How do I create a button that loops through all the line variables making one visible at a time?

Tags: button, kineticjs

How do I create a button that loops through all the line variables making one visible at a time?

I'm using Kinetic Javascript, I want to make a button that loops through all the line variables and every time i click that button it turns the next lines visiblity to "true" and the previous lines visibilty back to "false"

here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/NXt2L/4/

```
    <body>
  <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="show">
        show
      </button>
      <button id="hide">
        hide
      </button>
      <button id="reroute">
        reroute
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="kineticjs.js"></script>
    <script>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 1700,
        height: 1100
      });

    //Creates our layer to be put over the stage
    //note that we could have the building map as a layer itself and simply--
    //--put these muiltiple layers ontop of each other.
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();



      <!--Room 202-->
      var line202n = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(canvas) {
          var context = canvas.getContext();
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(454, 338);
          context.lineTo(440, 351);
          context.lineTo(533, 449);
          context.lineTo(565, 449);
          context.lineTo(635, 449);
          context.lineTo(635, 368);
          context.lineTo(591, 368);
          context.lineTo(591, 289);
          canvas.fillStroke(this);
        },
        stroke: 'blue',
        strokeWidth: 6,
        visible: false
      });
      layer.add(line202n);

      var line202s = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(canvas) {
          var context = canvas.getContext();
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(454, 338);
          context.lineTo(440, 351);
          context.lineTo(533, 449);
          context.lineTo(565, 449);
          context.lineTo(635, 449);
          context.lineTo(1432, 449);
          context.lineTo(1432, 532);
          canvas.fillStroke(this);
        },
        stroke: 'blue',
        strokeWidth: 6,
        visible: false
      });
      layer.add(line202s);


      //add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);

      // add button event bindings
        document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', 
        function() {
          line202n.show();
          layer.draw();
        }, false);

        document.getElementById('hide').addEventListener('click', function() {
          line202n.hide();
          layer.draw();
        }, false);

        document.getElementById('reroute').addEventListener('click', function() {
          line202n.hide();
          layer.draw();
        }, false);

      </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please includee your question in the body of your post.

Comment: If you put together a jsFiddle, then I be able to help you out some.

Comment: What it looks like you need to do is put all the coordinates into an array, create a setTimeout and execute one iteration of popping some elements off the end (or beginning) of the array and drawing them as a connected line. I recommend using Kinetic.Line() if you're just making lines rather than shapes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NXt2L/4/